# When a checkbox is checked means it automatically hide all the fields in a drupal form?

Tags: ajax

Any body know the answer please help me.my code is like this

```
function my_module_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['my_module/form'] = array(
        'title' => t('My form'),
        'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'description' => t('My form'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function my_module_form() {
    return drupal_get_form('my_module_my_form');
}
function my_module_my_form($form,$form_state) {
    echo "Billing Information";
    echo '<hr>';
    /*$form['checkbox'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title'=> 'HERE',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'checkbox1'
        ),
    );*/
    $form['store'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => "use my stored details",
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'checkbox1',
            'wrapper'=>'textfields',
        )

    );
    $form['previous'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        //'#disabled'=>'FALSE',
        '#title' => "use my details from the previous page",
    );

    /* $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );*/
    $form['fullname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Fullname'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#access'=> TRUE,
        '#description' => "Please enter your full name",
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['selectbox'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Country'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#height' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#options' => array(
            1 => 'Australia',
            2 => 'Burma',
            3 => 'China',
            4 => 'Denmark',
            5 => 'Egypt',
            6 => 'France',
            7 => 'Geneuva',
            8 => 'Holland',
            9 => 'India',
            10 => 'USA'
        ),
        '#description' => t('Please choose an option.'),
    );
    $form['address1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Address1'),
        '#description' => "please enter your Address1",
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['address2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Address2'),
        '#description' => "please enter your Address2",
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['city'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('City'),
        '#description' => "please enter your City name",
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['state'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('state'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#height' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#options' => array(
            1 => 'Assam',
            2 => 'Bihar',
            3 => 'Chandigar',
            4 => 'Gujarat',
            5 => 'Haryana',
            6 => 'Jammu',
            7 => 'Karnataka',
            8 => 'Maharsatra',
            9 => 'Orissa',
            10 => 'Punjab',
            11 => 'Rajasthan',
            12 => 'Tamilnadu',
            13 => 'Uttrapradesh',
            14 => 'WestBengal'
        ),
    );
    $form['zipcode'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Zipcode'),
        '#description' => "please enter your Zipcode",
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength'=> 255,
    );
    $form['ponumber'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('PO Number'),
        '#description' => "please enter your PO number",
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    return $form;
}

function my_module_my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'];
  if ($year_of_birth && ($year_of_birth < 1900 || $year_of_birth > 2000)) {
    form_set_error('year_of_birth', 'Enter a year between 1900 and 2000.');
  }
}

// Adds a submit handler/function to our form to send a successful
// completion message to the screen.

function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
function checkbox1($form, &$form_state) {
    //print_r($form);
    $form['fullname']['#access']=FALSE;
    //hide($form['fullname']);
    error_log(print_r($form,1));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Javascript will help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Drupal states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7), which is probably the easiest and doesn't require you to do any jQuery.  Here's an example:

```
$form['fullname'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Fullname'), 
  '#required' => TRUE, 
  '#access'=> TRUE, 
  '#description' => "Please enter your full name", 
  '#size' => 20, 
  '#maxlength' => 255,  
  '#states' => array(
    // Only show this field when the 'store' checkbox is enabled.
    'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="store"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Ya i need the sample drupal code for that for example my code is like this

Comment: Look at my answer above for an example.

Comment: Hi,shabana blackborder Thanks a lot it's working in a effective manner.............

Comment: If it's working please click on the grey checkbox next to the answer to accept it and reward the person who answered it as well as let the future visitors know that this is the best answer.

Comment: Instead of using #states i am in need of #access=>false please provide help for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also make use of this module [WebForm Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional)